# one to many relation with text parsing and sorting condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, one-to-many, qgis, many-to-one

I'm searching a sql query to make a new n:1 relation between two tables with some more conditions. Table_A has a fixed number of polygons with their unique IDs (varchar) in a column named "id_a". Table_B stores (a lot more) neighboured points of these polygons and their distance to a specific target. Each point in table_B has a column "poly_ids" that stores the neighboured polygons by there IDs as a comma-separated text, a unique ID called "id_b" and the distance attribute as just a value (double).

How can i find for each polygon the one neigboured point with the minimal distance attribute?

I tried already this and a couple of other things, but nothing worked out:

```
CREATE TABLE match AS 
    (SELECT id_a FROM table_A 
        (DECLARE my_id (varchar 255) := id_a)) 
    UNION
    (SELECT id_b FROM table_B 
        WHERE poly_ids LIKE '%my_id%'
           AND 
        table_B.distance <= MIN(table_B.distance);
```

I don´t know if this will find a match, but that´s the structue of the two tables:

Polygon-Table:

```
id_a;row
DENWLI0540200151;"1"
DENWLI0540201042;"2"
DENWLI0539203285;"3"
DENWLI0540200526;"4"
DENWLI0539200707;"5"
DENWLI0540200150;"6"
DENWLI0540200529;"7"
DENWLI0540211664;"8"
DENWLI0539203286;"9"
DENWLI0539200119;"10"
DENWLI0539202148;"11"
DENWLI0539200482;"12"
DENWLI0540200644;"13"
DENWLI0540202807;"14"
DENWLI0539202146;"15"
DENWLI0539200820;"16"
DENWLI0539200487;"17"
DENWLI0540200386;"18"
DENWLI0539200708;"19"
DENWLI0539200233;"20"
DENWLI0539203289;"21"
DENWLI0539202903;"22"
DENWLI0540200274;"23"
DENWLI0539202902;"24"
DENWLI0539201377;"25"
```

Neighbour Points_Table:

```
Distance_m;id_b;poly_ids
458.381978;"1";"DENWLI0540200151,DENWLI0539202146"
388.181258;"2";DENWLI0539203285
347.828999;"3";"DENWLI0539203285,DENWLI0539200630"
347.828999;"4";DENWLI0539203285
1121.671746;"5";DENWLI0540200526
147.780569;"6";DENWLI0540200526
1212.098782;"7";DENWLI0540200526
534.862435;"8";"DENWLI0540200526,DENWLI0540200300,DENWLI0540201374"
169.452134;"9";"DENWLI0540200526,DENWLI0540200090"
76.982818;"10";"DENWLI0540200526,DENWLI0540202246"
1040.426788;"11";"DENWLI0540200526,DENWLI0540202010"
55.631933;"12";"DENWLI0540200526,DENWLI0540202246"
66.441046;"13";"DENWLI0539200707,DENWLI0539202093,DENWLI0539200581"
192.089280;"14";"DENWLI0539200707,DENWLI0539202121"
330.531804;"15";"DENWLI0539200707,DENWLI0539200767"
337.169176;"16";"DENWLI0540200150,DENWLI0540200538"
729.729942;"17";DENWLI0540200150
136.210113;"18";DENWLI0540200529
498.361421;"19";DENWLI0540200529
428.060984;"20";DENWLI0540200529
170.279163;"21";DENWLI0540200529
```

The result should look like this, with id_b as the only one matching object with the most minimal distance:

```
id_a; id_b; Distance_m

DENWLI0540200151; "1";  458.381978
DENWLI0540201042; null; null
DENWLI0539203285; "2";  347.828999
DENWLI0540200526; "9";  169.452134
DENWLI0539200707; "13"; 66.441046
DENWLI0540200150; "16"; 337.169176
DENWLI0540200529; "18"; 136.210113
```

So the result list will be exactly as long as table_a. Or: It is table_a expanded with the best matching values from table_b (id_b and distance_m). If there is no match found for id_a, the values of id_b and distance are `id_a; null; null`. If there are more than one matching objects in table_b with exactly the same minimal distance, anyone of these can be used.

Comment: You can use LATERAL and functions to convert those comma separated values to a table. Would you please add some sample data and output expected.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Thanks Cetin, i posed two pictures of the two tables above. In the end a simple layer with two columns: id_a and the best fit of id_b (minimum distance of all fitting objects) would be fine.

Comment: Please do not post pictures but text. Pictures do not help much to create a sample.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Beneath two short csv-Versions:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Would be a mess as a comment)

I don't know what you are trying to get as a result, but for a simple one you could do this:

```
select *
from tableA a
         left join (
    select regexp_split_to_table(poly_ids, ',') polyId, id_b, distance_m from tableB) b on b.polyId = a.id_a;
```

EDIT: Get the min per id_a (only those that have a distance_m):

```
select id_a, min(b.distance_m)
from tableA a
         inner join (
    select regexp_split_to_table(poly_ids, ',') polyId, id_b, distance_m from tableB) b on b.polyId = a.id_a
group by id_a;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This brings me a great step further. With your lines i build a new table and did a new query with "select by id, min(distance)" and "group_by id" to receive just one result (out of table_b, with the most minimal distance) for each object of the polygon_table (table_a). But is there a way to do this and your code in just one query?

Comment: @stew, I am not really sure about the result you want. You are saying "one" result but grouping by some id would return many. Anyway, I am editing to add it but please make it clear by sampling what result you are after.

Comment: Sorry again for my bad explanation. I just have fragmented knowledge of sql. I posted the expected result in the origin question. The thing is: the regexp_split_function leads to more than one object for each id_a because the result list has all distances included. But i need to aggregate this list again to only one representation of id_a, BUT with the most minimal representation of id_b as distance. I found a lot of aggregation queries, but somehow they all aggregate for one column. Either the distance or the id. Mabe two aggregation cascades are needed?

Comment: Doesn't the second one solve your problem? (You might change inner to left join)

Comment: Perfect. That´s what i needed. Thank you and sorry for the late reply.